# Confusion about simple floating point load instruction

Tags: assembly, mips, intel

I had a question about the following floating point instruction and the '0' that is being transfered into f2 (floating point register)

```
fld f2,0(Rx)
```

What I know about this instruction from my research is that fld loads the contents of 0(Rx) to f2 and I know Rx is a integer/address register. I am just confused if the number 0 is being stored into f2 or the contents of Rx at 0

Comment: The 0 is just an offset applied to `Rx`.  The address used in the memory access is `Rx + 0`.

Comment: `fld` isn't a valid MIPS mnemonic.  Updated my answer.  Where did you get this instruction from, and why do you think it's x86?  Maybe it's not actually MIPS, but RISC-V or something else?  Lots of machines have `f` registers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Those operands look kind of like MIPS `l.d`**, not x86.

x86 `fld` in AT&T syntax looks like `fld 0(%esi)`, with an implicit destination of `st0`.

x87 stack register names are st0..st7.  x86+x87 doesn't have registers called f2.

---

MIPS on the other hand has integer/pointer registers r0..r31, and FP registers f0..f31, and `imm16 + register` with that syntax is (classic) MIPS' only addressing mode.

---

**But it's not MIPS either because `fld` isn't a MIPS mnemonic (it's x87)**, and most MIPS assemblers use `$` as a prefix on register names.

Like `l.d $f2, 0($4)` or `0($a0)` is normal MIPS syntax that will assemble with GAS or with MARS.  (And `l.d` is a pseudo-instruction for a double-precision load of 2 register.)

The actual machine instruction you want for MIPS is `ldc1 $f2, 0($4)`, for an alignment-required 64-bit load into $f2 and $f3.

---

**If it's for any actual ISA, it's probably not MIPS or x86, but I don't recognize a specific one.**

But regardless, this asm syntax is pretty universal: **It's a load into an FP register, and the source address is `0 + Rx`**